# Virtual Box with Fedora-Workstation-31-1.9 login GUI issue

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-31-1.9 on Virtual Box-5.2.22, installed successfully and I can login using tty however login GUI not working only black screen is shown. Is this something to do with graphic card?

Comment: (2) questions: 1) what video driver did you select for the VM, 2) why are you using such an old version of VB?

Comment: Hi @ajgringo619, 1) where can I check that? 2) this is my office system where don;t have admin access thus can't update to latest version. please help

Comment: From the Virtualbox Manager, select the VM, then Settings --> Display. You should see a dropdown menu where you can select other drivers. You may have to experiment with them.

Comment: Thanks for help @ajgringo619, this was the issue of video memory, by default it was 16MB, I made it to 80MB and now working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone getting the same issue, this was the issue of **video memory**

By default it was **16MB**, I made it to **80MB** and now working as expected.

Comment: could have been all sorts of issues as the root cause.